# Is Tomcat 4.1 compatible with MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc

We have a Tomcat 4.1 application that works well with MySQL 4.0.26.  I am attempting to upgrade MySQL to version 5.1 and Tomcat will not connect using JDBC.  Is it possible to have Tomcat 4.1 working with MySQL 5.1?

Comment: What version of the mysql-connector jar are you using?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.24-bin.jar

Comment: Whatever the answer to this question, you shoudl certainly upgrade your Tomcat. You are at best over four years and three major releases behind.